# Linq not returning all desired data

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have five entries in my database under the column "Name" that all start with 'pagetitle_dynamic_' and have different suffixes. I must be writing something improperly because only one result is getting returned. Any advice?

```
public ActionResult PageList()
{
    var keys = db.Keys.ToList();
    var prefix = "pagetitle_dynamic_";
    var display = keys.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(prefix));

    foreach (var item in display)
    { 
        var viewModel = new PageListViewModel
        {
            PageTitle = item.Name
        };

        List<PageListViewModel> viewModelList = new List<PageListViewModel>();
        viewModelList.Add(viewModel);                   

        return View(viewModelList);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are `return`ing inside the loop. Move it outside (and the declaration of `viewModelList`, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is malformed, as you see here.

```cs
foreach (var item in display)
{ 
      var viewModel = new PageListViewModel
      {
      PageTitle = item.Name
      };

      List<PageListViewModel> viewModelList = new List<PageListViewModel>();
      viewModelList.Add(viewModel);
      return View(viewModelList);
}
```

You have write `return View(viewModelList);` into the foreach loop, because of that the method is ending just when you have added the first list member to the view Model.

One possible solution could be:

```cs
public ActionResult PageList()
{
    List<PageListViewModel> viewModelList = new List<PageListViewModel>();
    var keys = db.Keys.ToList();
    var prefix = "pagetitle_dynamic_";
    var display = keys.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(prefix));

    foreach (var item in display)
    {
        var viewModel = new PageListViewModel
        {
            PageTitle = item.Name
        };

        viewModelList.Add(viewModel);
    }
    return View(viewModelList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @blorgbeard [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239239/linq-not-returning-all-desired-data#comment52360510_32239239), you need to move both the return call and the the construction of your list outside of the loop.

```
public ActionResult PageList()
{
    var keys = db.Keys.ToList();
    var prefix = "pagetitle_dynamic_";
    var display = keys.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(prefix));
    var viewModelList = new List<PageListViewModel>();

    foreach (var item in display)
    { 
         var viewModel = new PageListViewModel
        {
            PageTitle = item.Name
        };

        viewModelList.Add(viewModel);
    }

    return View(viewModelList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easier:

```
public ActionResult PageList()
{
    var keys = db.Keys.ToList();
    var prefix = "pagetitle_dynamic_";
    var display = keys.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(prefix));
    var viewModelList = new List<PageListViewModel>();

    return View(display.Select(item => new PageListViewModel
        {
            PageTitle = item.Name
        }
    ).ToList());
}
```